# Angular 9 migration issue declare var global: NodeJS.Global & typeof globalThis;

Tags: angular

As i have migrated the Angular 8 to Angular 9 but once the migration is completed i got this error which i tried some online resources but not able to solve it. See the below screen for error:

[image]

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "material",
  "private": true,
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "main": "",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf node_modules",
    "clean-all": "rimraf node_modules dist dll && npm cache clean",
    "init": "npm install",
    "reinstall": "rimraf node_modules && rm -f package-lock.json && npm install",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint-fix": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts --fix\"",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "hmr": "ng serve --hmr -e=hmr",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/http": "7.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/platform-server": "9.1.12",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.12",
    "@types/eventsource": "^1.0.2",
    "angular-animate": "^1.7.8",
    "angular-shepherd": "^0.3.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.4.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-labels": "^1.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "download-csv": "^1.1.1",
    "echarts": "^3.8.5",
    "exceljs": "^4.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-event-source": "^1.0.14",
    "ng2-ace-editor": "^0.3.9",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-odometer": "^1.1.3",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-shimmer-loading": "0.0.5",
    "panzoom": "^9.2.5",
    "postcss": "^7.0.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.12",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.12",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.42",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.6",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.4",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "ng-router-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^3.2.1",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "typescript": "3.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.21.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.9.4",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.0",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

My angular local version:

[image]

Please can anyone help on this as i have struck on this issue since so many days.

After googling i found some link and it says to run this below command:

```
npm ls @types/node
```

After running this command i got the below result. Which i dont understand.

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: your version of 'webpack-dev-server' is '~2.9.4'... try updating it to '3.1.4' and take another step.

Comment: @John Spiteri; I have changed but still getting the same issue.

Comment: var global: Global; (Global is the interface in Typescript), that is the first issue, and it looks like then it is conflicting with "zone.js" using the same values.

Running your command, I think you are using NPM version 6, which does not install peer dependencies... if you can update NPM to version 7, it will install the peer dependencies and make it easier to find what is required.